# Is it possible to deserialize ORC files in chunks?

Tags: amazon-s3, orc

I have a huge ORC object ( > 50GB) in S3. I would like to deserialize it in chunks (in a streaming manner). This allows me to retry from last offset in case of S3 file download failures.

I understand ORC stores metadata as a footer. So, I'm looking for some solution that reads the footer first, followed by chunked deserializing.

Answer (score 0):

s3 supports querying for specific file ranges over their http api. Assuming you know your stripe size ahead of time, you can use the api to get filesize. You can calculate the postscript offset, and download only it as a chunk. With  that metadata, you can then start pulling in the remainder of the file. It'd probably be best to do several requests, one for each stripe, and decode them concurrently.